# Wireless is disabled by hardware switch after connecting to ethernet

Tags: wireless, networking, ethernet, wifi-hardware-switch

I'm using dell with Ubuntu 12.04.

As soon as I connect ethernet, wireless gets disabled and network manager shows `Wireless is disabled by hardware switch` and, that status will go away after I unplug ethernet cable.

This is my rfkill list before connecting to ethernet.

```
1: phy0: Wireless  LAN
    Soft blocked:  no
    Hard blocked:  no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked:  no
    Hard blocked:  no
```

And this one is my rfkill list after connecting to ethernet.

```
1: phy0: Wireless  LAN
    Soft blocked:  no
    Hard blocked:  yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked:  no
    Hard blocked:  no

lspci Result for controllers:
    Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
    Network  controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
```

I'm trying to create a hotspot with ethernet (which worked perfectly well with ppp0) and I couldn't do that with current problem:

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
```

- What do I need to do, to solve that "hardware switch" problem?

Comment: Does you laptop have a physical switch for WiFi?

Comment: Ya. It does. But I didn't switch that off.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.  In my case it was a BIOS setting that said: "WAN - LAN switching" that caused the Wireless to get disabled when connecting the Ethernet.