# Wifi gets disabled when connecting to a wired network

Tags: networking, rfkill, connection-sharing

I have a HP Elitebook 8540w with Ubuntu 16.04. I am trying to share my wireless through ethernet but every time that I connect the ethernet cable the wireless gets disabled.

I searched the web for solutions but this doesn't seem to be network manager's default behavior.

This is what rfkill shows when the ethernet is connected:

```
$ sudo rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
```

And after unblock:

```
$ sudo rfkill unblock all
$ sudo rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: After investigating some more I realized this issue duplicates this one:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/403742/wireless-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch-after-connecting-to-ethernet

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the problem.  It turned out that my BIOS has an options that says: "WLAN - LAN switching" that I needed to uncheck.

Once unchecked phy0 is not disabled anymore when connecting the ethernet.